# Matlab slow while reading 24 bit integers

Tags: matlab

I found that reading data, which are packed in 24 bit integer format, using Matlab 'fread' with 'int24' option takes a lot of time.  I found that, if I read data in 'int32' or 'int16' or 'int8', the reading time is extremely faster as compared to 'int24'. Is there a better way to reduce the reduce the time for reading 24 bit integer data?

To get a feel of the problem, a sample code is given below.

```
clear all; close all; clc;

% generate some data and write it as a binary file
n=10000000;
x=randn(n,1);
fp=fopen('file1.bin', 'w');
fwrite(fp, x);
fclose(fp);

% read data in 24-bit format and measure the time
% please note that the data we get here will be different from 'x'.
% The sole purpose of the code is to demonstrate the delay in reading
% 'int24'

tic;
fp=fopen('file1.bin', 'r');
y1=fread(fp, n, 'int24');
fclose(fp);
toc;


% read data in 32-bit format and measure the time

% please note that the data we get here will be different from 'x'.
% The sole purpose of the code is to demonstrate the delay in reading
% 'int24'
tic;
fp=fopen('file1.bin', 'r');
y2=fread(fp, n, 'int32');
fclose(fp);
toc;
```

The output reads:
Elapsed time is 1.066489 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.047944 seconds.

Though the 'int32' version reads more data (32*n bits), it is 25 times faster than 'int24' reading.

Comment: Please provide sample code which also produces some sample file we can test on.

Comment: As suggested by Komarov, I updated the question with a sample code.

Comment: I can't find any references in the [MATLAB documentation on `fread` for a precision of `int24`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html), maybe that's why? AFAIK MATLAB only offers `int8`, `int16`, `int32` and `int64` in both signed and unsigned, and of course you can reverse the endianness. Can you try to read in triplets of `int8` instead?

Comment: @MarkMikofski it is actually `bitn` in the documentation. If you run the code, it throws a warning.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve about a 4x speedup by reading the data as unsigned 8-bit integers and combining each set of three bytes into the equivalent 24-bit number. Note that this assumes unsigned, little-endian values, so you would have to modify it to account for signed or big-endian data:

```
>> tic;
>> fp = fopen('file1.bin', 'r');
>> y1 = fread(fp, n, 'bit24');
>> fclose(fp);
>> toc;
Elapsed time is 0.593552 seconds.

>> tic;
>> fp = fopen('file1.bin', 'r');
>> y2 = double(fread(fp, n, '*uint8'));  % This is fastest, for some reason
>> y2 = [1 256 65536]*reshape([y2; zeros(3-rem(numel(y2), 3), 1)], 3, []);
>> fclose(fp);
>> toc;
Elapsed time is 0.143388 seconds.

>> isequal(y1,y2.')  % Test for equality of the values

ans =

     1
```

In the code above I just padded `y2` with zeroes to match the size of `y1`. The vector `y2` also ends up being a row vector instead of a column vector, which can be changed with a simple transpose if needed. For some reason having `fread` first output the values as `uint8`, then converting them to `double` was faster than any other option (i.e. outputting directly to `double` by making the last argument `'uint8'` or `'uint8=>double'`).

Answer (score 1):

First, it is better to use `bitn` instead of `int*`.

If you change `int24` to `bit32`, the code will run just as slow. So I think it is not about how many bits you read, rather the internal nature of using `bitn`.